# Does Staggering Strike work on undead if I can damage them with Sneak Attack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, undead

Staggerin Strike (feat, Complete Adventurer, p112):

> If you deal damage with a melee sneak attack [...] your target is treated **as if** it were staggered, even if its nonlethal damage doesn't exactly equal its current hit points [...] This feat has no effect on creatures not subject to sneak attack damage.

Grave Strike (spell, Spell Compendium, p107):

> [...] you can deliver sneak attacks against undead

I could read it either way:

- Not staggered: I did deal SA damage in this particular case, but the creature is "not subject to sneak attack damage"
- Staggered: The spell completely negates SA immunity for this attack

Can Grave Strike help to make an undead *staggered*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## It does not work

Staggering Strike has an important detail (unfortunately left out of the question):

> A target can resist this effect by making a successful **Fortitude** save.

However, undead are immune to most things requiring a Fortitude save:

> **Immunity** to any effect that requires a **Fortitude** save (unless the effect also works on objects or is harmless).

Answer (score 5):

It does [not work, due to the Fortitude save](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/149779/4563), but if we ignore that and focus just on the effect in the question...

Since Staggering Strike works on things that are “subject to sneak attack damage,” and *gravestrike* says that undead are (for you, anyway), Staggering Strike should indeed work on them.

Undead are not specifically immune to being staggered, but note that it is impossible for them to find themselves in that state in the normal way, since they are immune to nonlethal damage and destroyed at 0 hp. As a result, a DM *might* rule that the lack of staggered immunity on the undead type was due to the fact that it was impossible to get the condition at the time it was published, and that they “should” have it. With such a ruling, Staggering Strike would “work,” but the actual staggered condition it applies would do nothing.

Comment: it does not work, undead are immune to Fort saves, unless an object would also be affected.